# raspbian ssh connection refused after having enabled it

Tags: raspbian

I used sudo raspi-config, went into the advanced options, enabled ssh and tried with and without rebooting after this step, I am still getting Network Error: Connection refused
when trying to establish a connection via PuTTY

EDIT: It seems like the device isn't even connected to the network, even though I use DLAN to get it connected directly to the broadband router, the same DLAN I use to connect my primary desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: meaning on the broadband router? I will try doing that, what exactly am I looking for (very new to this kinda stuff sorry)

Comment: Most broadband routers allow you to log into them when you connect to the IP http://10.0.0.1/ on any standard web browser

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but I run into this same problem today when connecting to raspberry with Putty. In my case, the problem was that I used wlan instead of ethernet cable, and **hostname -i** gave the wrong Ip address.

I then run **ifconfig**, and realized that there was different Ip address for wlan. With that Ip address, Putty and Filezilla connected right away to my raspberry.

Hope that this will help someone.